# Книги по разработке системы GUI

Tags: книги, gui, embedded

Видел много книг по написанию и устройству ОС. Это да.

А вот про то, как делать интерфейс к ним (пустым ОС) с API соответствующим я, при поверхностном поиске, не нашёл толковых книжек, тем более на русском языке.

Методы создания объектов, удаления, работа с событиями этих элементов, отрисовка их, картинки, шрифты, структуры, дескрипторы... Представление в памяти всего этого. И как сделать это экономно и быстро. Что-то из этой оперы.

Сама по себе компьютерная графика мало интересна - алгоритмов и книжек по ней тоже много.
Буду делать это или нет, - я не знаю, но почитать летом сабж было бы весьма приятственно.

Comment: Разные они. Можно порекомендовать книги по tcl/tk (классика, тем более, что и сейчас используется активно). Ссылки на книги - google в помощь. Ну а win-специфичные - Петцольд. :)

Comment: Не, я не про конкретно какую-то программу, а вообще, глобально =) Вот есть пустая ось тока с менеджером ресурсов, а надо к ней ещё и GUI. Есть готовые библиотеки, но интересна теория их создания.

Comment: GTK, QT, wxWindow... - это все обертки. По факту они работают или поверх X Windows (*nix) или Win32API (ес-но Win). Получается, библиотеки графических компонентов и сама оконная среда - разные вещи. Цель первых - удобно упаковать вызовы ф-ций оконной среды и выйти на более высокий уровень абстракции. Заодно это ведет к возможности реализации многоплатформенности. А сама оконная среда, очевидно, опирается на вызовы ядра ОС и драйверов.  И поэтому переносимой может быть постольку-поскольку. Учитывая, что написание оконных сред - сфера весьма узкая, то и доков я не видел толковых.

Comment: Могу предложить разве что изучить следующие материалы:<p>
- исходные коды WinNT4, Win2k, благо они в сеть утекли;<p>
- можно еще глянуть на ReactOS, т.к. они тоже реализуют Win32API, но по-своему.<p>
- исходные коды X Window System - стандартной граф. среды Linux и менеджеров окон fvwm, twm и Co (чем проще - тем лучше);<p>
- исходные коды MenuetOS - маленькой ОСи на asm'е с граф. оболочкой<p>

Comment: Тебя интересует реализация. Не думаю что по этой тебе будут книги. Видимо остаётся лишь изучать сорцы Gtk/Gdk. Возможно пригодится книга Джефа Раскина "The Human Interface".

Answer (score 1):

Книг не знаю, не читал таких. Есть серия статей ["Developing a GUI Using C++ and DirectX" by Mason McCuskey](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/directx/258/developing-a-gui-using-c-and-directx-part-1-r994) - о разработке системы "оконного" интерфейса (не забыли, что кнопки - тоже окна, только особого вида/класса?)

Не смотрите на слово DirectX - он там только для рендеринга, а Вы сами указали что по **этой** тематике литературы навалом.

К сожалению, на английском. Возможно, на русском ГеймДеве перевели, но утверждать не стану, не уверен.